# How do i select the correct facebook preview image per link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have an overview page of 15 routes and on each line i have img | text | and a corresponding share on facebook link. Now i like to have each route have the correct image as preview on facebook.

Right now i have 15 og:image in the  part but that didn't work.

regards

Comment: You have to have an individual URL for every single item you want to be liked.

Comment: @CBroe, hmm i was afraid it was something like that. So no workaround (iframes)? Just checked my url on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it doesn't parse any errors.